# Can I use my Un-Managed Namespace on the Managed Package?

Tags: managed-package

I have an un-managed beta package with a Namespace uploaded.  I've finished testing and want to upload it as a Managed package.  When I select upload and Managed package.  It doesn't give me an option to change the namespace. Do I have to change the namespace when I convert a un-managed beta package to a manage package?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as an unmanaged beta package. The namespace applies to the developer edition org, can only be set once, and can never be removed or modified. Your managed package will have the namespace you've already chosen in your developer edition org.